# 3d Max script (.ms) file run from CLI(Command Line Interface)

Tags: php, 3dsmax

I have a 3d max demo.ms script file.
I need to run it from `CLI(Command Line Interface)` .
Please provide me any link. I am beginner.

Answer (score 0):

There's no real commandline only option in max. You can only start max from the commandline with a script as parameter, once max has started it will execute the script. There's also some scripts around that register a com port or socket server to which you can sent commands too.

Comment: You should ans after Google.
get the link and see
http://docs.autodesk.com/3DSMAX/15/ENU/3ds-Max-Help/files/GUID-B30BA517-B3C1-4D7C-AFB6-B220C2EDC529.htm

Comment: That commandline tool is only for submitting renders to backburner, I thought you wanted more something like changing scene properties on many files without opening max. It doesn't provide an interactive session with max, where you can do things from the commandline. Maybe you should provide some more information about what it is you want to do, the question is very broad.